# Verbose level with argparse and multiple -v options

Tags: python, argparse

I'd like to be able to specify different verbose level, by adding more -v options to the command line. For example:

```
$ myprogram.py    
$ myprogram.py -v
$ myprogram.py -vv
$ myprogram.py -v -v -v
```

would lead to verbose=0, verbose=1, verbose=2, and verbose=3 respectively. How can I achieve that using argparse?

Optionally, it could be great to also be able to specify it like

```
$ myprogram -v 2
```

Comment: You should consider marking [Ben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335918/202522) as the correct answer, since people find this via google searches, and the `-v 2` feature and custom snippet are over the top for most users.`

Comment: @joar: yes indeed. thanks for your comment pointing to the correct answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could do this with `nargs='?'` (to accept 0 or 1 arguments after the `-v` flag) and a custom action (to process the 0 or 1 arguments):

```
import sys
import argparse

class VAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, nargs=None, const=None, 
                 default=None, type=None, choices=None, required=False, 
                 help=None, metavar=None):
        super(VAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, nargs, const, 
                                      default, type, choices, required, 
                                      help, metavar)
        self.values = 0
    def __call__(self, parser, args, values, option_string=None):
        # print('values: {v!r}'.format(v=values))
        if values is None:
            self.values += 1
        else:
            try:
                self.values = int(values)
            except ValueError:
                self.values = values.count('v')+1
        setattr(args, self.dest, self.values)

# test from the command line
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', nargs='?', action=VAction, dest='verbose')
args = parser.parse_args()
print('{} --> {}'.format(sys.argv[1:], args))

print('-'*80)

for test in ['-v', '-v -v', '-v -v -v', '-vv', '-vvv', '-v 2']:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-v', nargs='?', action=VAction, dest='verbose')
    args=parser.parse_args([test])
    print('{:10} --> {}'.format(test, args))
```

Running `script.py -v -v` from the command line yields

```
['-v', '-v'] --> Namespace(verbose=2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-v         --> Namespace(verbose=1)
-v -v      --> Namespace(verbose=2)
-v -v -v   --> Namespace(verbose=3)
-vv        --> Namespace(verbose=2)
-vvv       --> Namespace(verbose=3)
-v 2       --> Namespace(verbose=2)
```

Uncomment the print statement to see better what the `VAction` is doing.

Comment: a custom action is not (no longer) required. see the answer from **Ben**.

Comment: Very educational, but... Verbose is `None` when not specified (maybe `0` was expected). It also doesn't play well when you have other options (not just one), and you want to have free order of arguments.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it doesn't even work. When you pass `-v` multiple times on an actual command line, you don't get `['-v -v -v']`, you get `['-v', '-v', '-v']`, and for that your code gives `verbose=1`.

Comment: @TomaszGandor: Thanks for the bug report. The issue with multiple `-v`s has been corrected.

Answer (score 185):

argparse supports [`action='count'`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', action='count', default=0)

for c in ['', '-v', '-v -v', '-vv', '-vv -v', '-v -v --verbose -vvvv']:
    print(parser.parse_args(c.split()))
```

Output:

```
Namespace(verbose=0)
Namespace(verbose=1)
Namespace(verbose=2)
Namespace(verbose=2)
Namespace(verbose=3)
Namespace(verbose=7)
```

The only very minor niggle is you have to explicitly set `default=0` if you want no `-v` arguments to give you a verbosity level of 0 rather than `None`.

Comment: This does not allow for `myprogram -v 2` syntax. Meanwhile `action='count'` has appeared in the docs.

Comment: This seems to be the best and easiest answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Doesn't fulfill ops optional requirement, but is really easy and good enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You could handle the first part of your question with `append_const`. Otherwise, you're probably stuck writing a custom action, as suggested in the fine [answer by unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076690/verbose-level-with-argparse-and-multiple-v-options/6076779#6076779).

```
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-v', action = 'append_const', const = 1)

for c in ['', '-v', '-v -v', '-vv', '-vv -v']:
    opt = ap.parse_args(c.split())
    opt.v = 0 if opt.v is None else sum(opt.v)
    print opt
```

Output:

```
Namespace(v=0)
Namespace(v=1)
Namespace(v=2)
Namespace(v=2)
Namespace(v=3)
```

Comment: I like this solution; I think the simplicity of code afforded by using `append_const` is worth giving up `-v 2` for.

Comment: Choosing which answer I would accept wasn't an easy choice. I like the simplicity of your answer.

Comment: Using `append_const` also lets you add a `-q` argument. With `dest='v', const=-1`, it will then undo any `-v`. I use that with a `default=[2]` so I can map the result to logging module levels, starting at WARN and letting you -q/v up and down the scale.

Comment: The `-vv` input doesn't work if you set `allow_abbrev=False`. But you can still do `-v -v`

Answer (score 9):

Here's my take on this that doesn't use any new classes, works in both Python 2 and 3 and supports relative adjustments from the default using "-v"/"--verbose" and "-q"/"--quiet", but it **doesn't** support using numbers e.g. "-v 2":

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
import logging
import sys

LOG_LEVELS = ["DEBUG", "INFO", "WARNING", "ERROR", "CRITICAL"]
DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL = "INFO"


def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--verbose", "-v",
        dest="log_level",
        action="append_const",
        const=-1,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--quiet", "-q",
        dest="log_level",
        action="append_const",
        const=1,
    )

    args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
    log_level = LOG_LEVELS.index(DEFAULT_LOG_LEVEL)

    # For each "-q" and "-v" flag, adjust the logging verbosity accordingly
    # making sure to clamp off the value from 0 to 4, inclusive of both
    for adjustment in args.log_level or ():
        log_level = min(len(LOG_LEVELS) - 1, max(log_level + adjustment, 0))

    log_level_name = LOG_LEVELS[log_level]
    print(log_level_name)
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(log_level_name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Example:

```
$ python2 verbosity.py -vvv
DEBUG
$ python3 verbosity.py -vvv -q
INFO
$ python2 verbosity.py -qqq -vvv -q
WARNING
$ python2 verbosity.py -qqq
CRITICAL
```

Comment: I really liked this implementation. Its very clean, however, it has some flaws. Your log_level is not the same log level from logging library, so it would still need to translate them. Another thing is that logging level work the other way around, the lower, the more critical, so I would inverted the consts from -q and -v. It works fine now.

Comment: @MtCS, I used the default strings in the logging library, so all you need to do is `logger.setLevel(log_level_name)` assuming you're not using any additional strings. As for the part of about the constants, it literally makes no difference. In my mind, the log level is verbosity which is why I used `+1` for "-v" and `-1` for "-q", but again, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on unutbu's answer, here's a custom action including handling of a --quiet/-q combination. This is tested in Python3. Using it in Python >=2.7 should be no big deal.

```
class ActionVerbose(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, args, values, option_string=None):
        #print(parser, args, values, option_string)
        # Obtain previously set value in case this option call is incr/decr only
        if args.verbose == None:
            base = 0
        else:
            base = args.verbose
        # One incr/decr is determined in name of option in use (--quiet/-q/-v/--verbose)
        option_string = option_string.lstrip('-')
        if option_string[0] == 'q':
            incr = -1
        elif option_string[0] == 'v':
            incr = 1
        else:
            raise argparse.ArgumentError(self,
                                         'Option string for verbosity must start with v(erbose) or q(uiet)')
        # Determine if option only or values provided
        if values==None:
            values = base + incr
        else:
            # Values might be an absolute integer verbosity level or more 'q'/'v' combinations
            try:
                values = int(values)
            except ValueError:
                values = values.lower()
                if not re.match('^[vq]+$', values):
                    raise argparse.ArgumentError(self,
                                                 "Option string for -v/-q must contain only further 'v'/'q' letters")
                values = base + incr + values.count('v') - values.count('q')
        setattr(args, self.dest, values)
    @classmethod
    def add_to_parser(cls,
                      parser, dest='verbose', default=0,
                      help_detail='(0:errors, 1:info, 2:debug)'):
        parser.add_argument('--verbose', nargs='?', action=ActionVerbose, dest=dest, metavar='level',
                            default=default,
                            help='Increase or set level of verbosity {}'.format(help_detail))
        parser.add_argument('-v',        nargs='?', action=ActionVerbose, dest=dest, metavar='level',
                            help='Increase or set level of verbosity')
        parser.add_argument('--quiet',   nargs='?', action=ActionVerbose, dest=dest, metavar='level',
                            help='Decrease or set level of verbosity')
        parser.add_argument('-q',        nargs='?', action=ActionVerbose, dest=dest, metavar='level',
                            help='Decrease or set level of verbosity')
```

There's a convenience class method which can be used to set up all four option handlers for `--verbose`, `-v`, `-q`, `--quiet`. Use it like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ActionVerbose.add_to_parser(parser, default=defaults['verbose'])
# add more arguments here with: parser.add_argument(...)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When using a script having these arguments you can do:

```
./script -vvvvvv -v 4 -v 0 -v -vvv --verbose --quiet 2 -v qqvvqvv
```

With this command line `args.verbose` would be `4`.

- Any `-v/-q/--verbose/--quiet` with a given number is a hard, absolute set of `args.verbose` to that given number (=verbosity level).
- Any `-v/--verbose` without a number is an increment of that level.
- Any `-q/--quiet` without a number is a decrement of that level.
- Any `-v/-q` may immediately be followed up with more `v/q` letters, the resulting level is `the old level + sum(count('v')) - sum(count('q'))`
- Overall default is 0

The custom action should be fairly easy to modify in case you want a different behaviour. For example, some people prefer that any `--quiet` resets the level to 0, or even to -1. For this, dremove the `nargs` from the add_argument of `-q` and `--quiet`, and also hardcode to set `value = 0` `if option_string[0] == 'q'`.

Proper parser errors are nicely printed if usage is wrong:

```
./script -vvvvvv -v 4 -v 0 -v -vvv --verbose --quiet 2 -v qqvvqvav
usage: script [-h] [--verbose [level]]
              [-v [level]] [--quiet [level]] [-q [level]]
script: error: argument -v: Option string for -v/-q must contain only further 'v'/'q' letters
```

Comment: I really like this, but it seems that 'defaults' are missing and default=defaults['verbose']) will not work? Sorry if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

`argparse` supports the `append` action which lets you specify multiple arguments. Check http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html, search for "`append`".

Answer (score 0):

Your first proposed method would be more likely to confuse. Different option names for different levels of verbosity, or one verbose flag optionally followed by a numeric indicator of the level of verbosity is less likely to confuse a user and would allow more flexibility in assigning verbosity levels.

Comment: This method isn't uncommon. For example, SSH uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an alternative; while it doesn't *exactly* match OP's request, it fulfilled my requirements and I thought it worth sharing.

Use a mutually exclusive group to either count the number of short options or store the integer value of a long option.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
verbosity_group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
verbosity_group.add_argument(
  '-v',
  action='count',
  dest='verbosity',
  help='Turn on verbose output. Use more to turn up the verbosity level'
)
verbosity_group.add_argument(
  '--verbose',
  action='store',
  type=int,
  metavar='N',
  dest='verbosity',
  help='Set verbosity level to `N`'
)
parser.set_defaults(
  verbosity=0
)
parser.parse_args()
```

```
parser.parse_args([])
# Namespace(verbosity=0)
parser.parse_args(['-v', '-vv'])
# Namespace(verbosity=3)
parser.parse_args(['--verbose=4'])
# Namespace(verbosity=4)
parser.parse_args(['--verbose'])
# error: argument --verbose: expected one argument
```

As you can see, it allows you to "stack" single char options and allows you to use the long option name to set the value explicitly.  The downside is that you cannot use the long option as a switch (the last example generates an exception.)